# Recursion not working

Tags: difference-equations

I am trying to find the terms x7,x8,x9 and so on from the recursive relation given in the code.

```
Clear["Golbal`*"]
eq = {x[0] == 0, x[1] == 0, x[2] == a1/2, 
     x[3] == 1/6, x[4] == (k^2*a1)/12, 
     x[5] == (1/120)*(2*k^2 + k*R*a2), 
     x[6] == (k^4*a1)/240, y[0] == 0, y[1] == a2, 
     y[2] == 0, y[3] == (k^2*a2)/6, 

     (n + 1)*(n + 2)*(n + 3)*(n + 4)*x[n + 4] - 2*k^2*(n + 1)*(n + 2)*x[n + 2] + k^4*x[n] - 
         k*R*(y[n] - p*y[n - 3]) == 0, 
     (n + 1)*(n + 2)*y[n + 2] - k^2*y[n] + k*x[n] == 0}
res = RSolve[eq, {x[n], y[n]}, n]; 
resx[n_] = x[n] /. res; 
resy[n_] = y[n] /. res; 
FullSimplify[TableForm[Table[{i, resx[i]}, {i, 1, 10}]]]
```

I am getting an error and am unable to figure out the reason. However, solving this relation by hand I get the x terms but this seems to be very time-consuming as I have to find many such terms. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ```Clear["Golbal`*"]``` should be ```Clear["Global`*"]``` . It would help if you provided the error. In this case it appears to be a replacement failure, because RSolve cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them by repeated solving and adding to your list of found x,y:

First define:

```
x[0] = 0;
x[1] = 0;
x[2] = a1/2;
x[3] = 1/6;
x[4] = (k^2*a1)/12;
x[5] = (1/120)*(2*k^2 + k*R*a2);
x[6] = (k^4*a1)/240;
y[-3] = 0;
y[-2] = 0;
y[-1] = 0;
y[0] = 0;
y[1] = a2;
y[2] = 0;
y[3] = (k^2*a2)/6;

eqns = {(n + 1)*(n + 2)*(n + 3)*(n + 4)*x[n + 4] - 
     2*k^2*(n + 1)*(n + 2)*x[n + 2] + k^4*x[n] - 
     k*R*(y[n] - p*y[n - 3]) == 0,
   (n + 1)*(n + 2)*y[n + 2] - k^2*y[n] + k*x[n] == 0};
```

```
Solve[eqns /. n -> 1]
(* {{ }} *)

Solve[eqns /. n -> 2]
(* {{y[4] -> -((a1 k)/24)}} *)

y[4] = -((a1 k)/24);
Solve[eqns /. n -> 3]
(* {{x[7] -> (k^3 (k + a2 R))/1680, y[5] -> 1/120 k (-1 + a2 k^3)}} *)

x[7] = (k^3 (k + a2 R))/1680;
y[5] = 1/120 k (-1 + a2 k^3);
Solve[eqns /. n -> 4]
(* {{x[8] -> (k (4 a1 k^5 - a1 k R - 24 a2 p R))/40320, y[6] -> -((a1 k^3)/240)}} *)

x[8] = (k (4 a1 k^5 - a1 k R - 24 a2 p R))/40320;
y[6] = -((a1 k^3)/240);
Solve[eqns /. n -> 5]
(* {{x[9] -> (k^2 (4 k^4 - R + 6 a2 k^3 R))/362880, 
     y[7] -> (k^2 (-3 k + a2 k^4 - a2 R))/5040}} *)

x[9] = (k^2 (4 k^4 - R + 6 a2 k^3 R))/362880;
y[7] = (k^2 (-3 k + a2 k^4 - a2 R))/5040;
```

We can automate this as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
defs = <|
   x[0] -> 0,
   x[1] -> 0,
   x[2] -> a1/2,
   x[3] -> 1/6,
   x[4] -> (k^2*a1)/12,
   x[5] -> (1/120)*(2*k^2 + k*R*a2),
   x[6] -> (k^4*a1)/240,
   y[-3] -> 0,
   y[-2] -> 0,
   y[-1] -> 0,
   y[0] -> 0,
   y[1] -> a2,
   y[2] -> 0,
   y[3] -> (k^2*a2)/6|>;

eqns = {(n + 1)*(n + 2)*(n + 3)*(n + 4)*x[n + 4] - 
     2*k^2*(n + 1)*(n + 2)*x[n + 2] + k^4*x[n] - 
     k*R*(y[n] - p*y[n - 3]) == 0,
   (n + 1)*(n + 2)*y[n + 2] - k^2*y[n] + k*x[n] == 0};

Do[
 AppendTo[defs, #] & /@ First[Solve[eqns /. {n -> i} /. defs]]
 , {i, 2, 10}]
```

This gives me:

```
<|x[0] -> 0,
  x[1] -> 0,
  x[2] -> a1/2,
  x[3] -> 1/6, 
  x[4] -> (a1 k^2)/12,
  x[5] -> 1/120 (2 k^2 + a2 k R), 
  x[6] -> (a1 k^4)/240,
  y[-3] -> 0,
  y[-2] -> 0,
  y[-1] -> 0,
  y[0] -> 0, 
  y[1] -> a2,
  y[2] -> 0,
  y[3] -> (a2 k^2)/6,
  y[4] -> -((a1 k)/24), 
  x[7] -> (k^3 (k + a2 R))/1680,
  y[5] -> 1/120 k (-1 + a2 k^3), 
  x[8] -> (k (4 a1 k^5 - a1 k R - 24 a2 p R))/40320, 
  y[6] -> -((a1 k^3)/240), 
  x[9] -> (k^2 (4 k^4 - R + 6 a2 k^3 R))/362880, 
  y[7] -> (k^2 (-3 k + a2 k^4 - a2 R))/5040, 
  x[10] -> (k^3 (5 a1 k^5 - 5 a1 k R - 168 a2 p R))/3628800, 
  y[8] -> -((a1 k^5)/6720), 
  x[11] -> (k^2 (5 k^6 - 5 k^2 R + 10 a2 k^5 R + 210 a1 p R - a2 k R^2))/39916800,
  y[9] -> (k^4 (-6 k + a2 k^4 - 4 a2 R))/362880, 
  x[12] -> (k^2 (2 a1 k^8 - 5 a1 k^4 R + 112 p R - 216 a2 k^3 p R))/159667200,
  y[10] -> (-10 a1 k^7 + a1 k^3 R + 24 a2 k^2 p R)/3628800,
  x[13] -> (k^4 (2 k^6 - 5 k^2 R + 5 a2 k^5 R + 644 a1 p R - 2 a2 k R^2))/2075673600, 
  y[11] -> (k^3 (-10 k^4 + a2 k^7 + R - 10 a2 k^3 R))/39916800, 
  x[14] -> (1/87178291200)k^3 (7 a1 k^9 - 35 a1 k^5 R + 2832 k p R - 1848 a2 k^4 p R + a1 k R^2 + 744 a2 p R^2), 
  y[12] -> (-5 a1 k^9 + 2 a1 k^5 R + 64 a2 k^4 p R)/159667200|>
```

Comment: The code runs but there is no output displayed. Maybe I have have to print the output after the `Do` command? Also, the conditions `y[-3] = 0; y[-2] = 0; y[-1] = 0;` are not defined for my problem.

Comment: The output is in `defs`. Just put `defs` in a cell an run it. @Math_student

Comment: Those conditions aren't strictly necessary, but you need them if you want your conditions to be consistent with the equation. @Math_student

Comment: How can I get terms upto `x[25]` and `y[25]`?

Comment: @Math_student in the loop, increase the 10 in `{i, 2, 10}` to something bigger. You'll be waiting a long time though.

Comment: Taking `{i, 2, 23}` makes the program run for more than an hour with no output. Is there a way to get the result sooner?